# Why am I getting performance issues on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance

I have recently bought a new laptop, mostly to use for music production. This was an upgrade from my last PC and the performance, at least I believed, should have been better across the board, with my old PC having 4GB of RAM and an i3 that on cpubenchmark.net, got a score of 2300. My new laptop has an i7-10510U which gets a score of 7400 and 8GB of RAM.

My issue is that while using the laptop with my music production software, I run into very poor performance - performance that I did not encounter with my previous PC which, though it would take a while to load project files up and the like, did not seem to have any issues once things were actually loaded. The type of issue that I am encountering is something that *would* be related to CPU speed - however when I run into the problems, checking on task manager shows me that the CPU doesn't even seem to be stressed or aware that the program that I am running is choking up due to apparent lack of CPU power.

I've searched high and wide through the support forums for the software I am using (FL Studio) and changed everything that I have been recommended to but to no avail. I am now wondering if there are any obvious settings I have missed in my laptop that are preventing it from using all of its CPU power or if I am just out of luck with regards to getting consistent performance.

Comment: Laptops tend to have painfully atrocious mechanical hard disk drives. They can cause a system to feel slow. Upgrading to an SSD can help.

Comment: The laptop did come with an 512GB SSD - I'm not sure of any specifics about it that might make a difference however.

Comment: 8GB of RAM seems to be a bare minimum nowadays, especially with a CPU like this. If you can add RAM, I'd recommend an extra 8GB, provided there's a free slot down there. Also, with an SSD, you might want to reduce read-write so as not to wear your drive. I use this little freeware (here: http://www.totalidea.com/products/tweak-ssd/) to optimize my SSDs, and it does bring a little extra ooomph once you've rebooted.

Comment: Is there any difference between running on battery and from your power adaptor? Full system specs might help here.

Comment: There isn't any obvious difference on battery or plugged in - I have had it plugged in for the majority of the time that I am using it however if that changes anything. 

As for the RAM situation - is it the case that if my computer has more RAM that it will be able to utilise the CPU better?

Comment: As you say it occurs both on power and battery it seems not to be related to power saving features, but just to be sure: when you click the battery icon in the taskbar when you're plugged in, does it show you that you're using the "best performance" setting? Or does it say something like "best batter life"?